# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) on("data")

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, https

I tried using other api and it worked, however it does not work with this one.

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get("/",(req, res)=>{
https.get("https://pixabay.com/api/?key=xxx-zzz&q=yellow+flowers&image_type=photo", (response)=>{
   console.log(response.statusCode);
       response.on("data",d=>{
           const lala = JSON.parse(d);
           console.log(lala);
       })
    
    })
});
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("Server started on port 3000")
})
```

I got this in the console

> 200
> undefined:1
> {"total":28739,"totalHits":500,"hits":[{"id":3063284,"pageURL":"https://pixabay.com/photos/rose-flower-petal-floral-noble-3063284/","type":"photo","tags":"rose, flower, petal","previewURL":"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/05/16/24/rose-3063284_150.jpg","previewWidth":150,"previewHeight":99,"webformatURL":"https://pixaba
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
> at JSON.parse ()

Comment: Is there another `console.log()` that you don't show in the snippet? Where is `undefined:1` coming from?

Comment: You have three outputs in the console and I can only find 2 console.logs. something is missing. And a piece of advise, never share a code snippet with sensitive info like API key. It'd be wise if you omit the API from your snippet.

Comment: @SiradjiAwoual Thank you for the adviced. I won't do it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`data` event](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) does not mean that a request has completed. Request data is sent in packets.

Use the `data` event to collect all the data and then combine it in the `end` event before interacting with your data:

```js
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get("/",(req, res)=>{
https.get("https://pixabay.com/api/?key=xxx-zzz&q=yellow+flowers&image_type=photo", (response)=>{
   console.log(response.statusCode);
       let chunks = [];
       response.on("data",d=>{
           chunks.push(d);
       });
       response.on("end",()=>{
           const lala = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8'));
           console.log(lala);
       });
    });
});
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```